# jni correct checking of which functions return values?

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm correctly doing what I want with JNI (at least it works! ;) ) however while developing I used a bunch of asserts (just to be sure each step was okay)

Now I'm actually working, which return values should be checked and which can I assume will return sane values and shouldn't need checking

here's some support code used by a number of my jni calls

```
// given a jni env and NVGpaint this creates a java object
// encapsulating the NVGpaint structure (nvg.Paint)
jobject createPaintJobject(JNIEnv *e, NVGpaint p) 
{
    jclass cls = (*e)->FindClass(e, "nvg$Paint");
    assert(cls != NULL);
    jmethodID constructor = (*e)->GetMethodID(e, cls, "<init>", "()V");
    assert(constructor != NULL);

    jobject nvgpaint = (*e)->NewObject(e, cls, constructor);
    assert(nvgpaint!=NULL);

    jfieldID fid = (*e)->GetFieldID(e, cls,"buff","Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;");
    assert(fid != NULL);
    jobject jbuff = (*e)->GetObjectField(e, nvgpaint, fid);
    assert(jbuff != NULL);
    NVGpaint* ptr = (void*)(*e)->GetDirectBufferAddress(e, jbuff);
    assert(ptr!=NULL);
    *ptr = p;
    return nvgpaint;
}
```

what's best practise in replacing these asserts and do some of them even need checking?

Comment: All JNI calls need checking, and assertion is not the way to do it.

Comment: No kidding that's exactly what I'm asking....

Answer (score 0):

**what's best practise in replacing these asserts?**

By using the exception checking mechanism might be better in comparison with these asserts.

```
    env->ExceptionCheck();
    env->ExceptionClear();
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
    env->ExceptionOccurred();
```

Actually you should always do the exception checking when call those JNI functions that can raise exception.